# Exercise Agency Over Their Learning - Use Of Agency

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

I was just watching [this TED talk featuring Sal Kan *Let's teach for mastery -- not test scores*](https://youtu.be/-MTRxRO5SRA) and in it Sal uses the word **Agency** in a very unfamiliar way to me. He uses it almost a dozen times in the same manner one of which can be viewed and heard at the [10:20 mark here](https://youtu.be/-MTRxRO5SRA). He says, "Exercise agency over their learning." What does the use of *agency* mean in this context?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As a reminder, questions should indicate the initial research attempted, so that answerers do not repeat work that has already been done. This question would have been greatly strengthened, for example, by indicating which dictionaries you checked and why the listed meanings did not seem to fit. If meanings do fit, the question may be deemed general reference and closed. I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context it means the capacity to exert their own will and make their own choices. See [definition (2)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agency).

Comment: I've never heard agency used in that form of the definition before so wasn't aware of it's usage like that. Thanks this makes sense now.